# Why do some root and intermediate certificate authorities have "G2" or "G3" in the name?

Tags: tls, certificate-authority, root

I have noticed that some root and intermediate CAs have things like "G2" or "G3" in the name.

For example, take the certificate for [amazon.com](https://www.amazon.com/). The intermediate CA is DigiCert Global CA G2, and the root CA is DigiCert Global Root G2.

I understand that "G2" means "Generation 2." But what is the purpose of having a second-generation CA? What changed between the first and second generations?

Comment: You can find the response to your question on https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/19093/what-does-g2-mean-when-used-with-x509-certficates-and-certificate-authorities#47196

Answer (score 0):

Quoted from [Tombart's answer](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/47196/54167) on Crypto SE:

> Yes, G stands for "Generation". When CA needs to get a new chain they
>   just increment the generation number.
>
> For example GoDaddy's signatures:
>
> - `G3` - `sha256WithRSAEncryption`
> - `G4` - `ecdsa-with-SHA384`